# Convert JSON url to HTML URL

Tags: html, json

http://www.hulu.com/mozart/v1.h2o/shows/54/episodes?show_id=54&sort=seasons_and_release&video_type=episode&_language=en&_region=us&items_per_page=32&position=1&_user_pgid=1&_device_id=1&access_token=sTEbtl-07BZKws2iXobQFRWRzsA%3D8gQbJIixd5b6b896ddf9e57468c8f629c56ca14bcaba6e85ec2664236998c57f6dce5759ae4bbceb1f6442e53302cb02e8ba121f

Need to convert this JSON URL to HTML URL! If we hit the above URL am getting only the JSON script and i want to convert it into HTML table where i can apply xpath to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the response by yourself. jQuery can do that: (short example)

```
var doc = $('#table');
$.getJSON('url', function (res) {
    $.each(res, function (x) {     
    doc.append('<tr>');
    doc.append('<td>'+x.description+'</td>');
    doc.append('</tr>');
    });
});
```